# SaveAs works in Excel 2010, but causes automation error in 2013, 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013, save-as, vba

`SaveAs` in VBA works in Excel 2010, but in Excel 2013, 2016 *automation error* occurs and Excel gets closed when executed for the second time.

```
'Move the Result SeqMergeSheet
rpath = ThisWorkbook.Path 'Tools path
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SeqMergeSheet").Move  ' From Tool Workbook

'Save as the result
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs rpath & "\" & "TotalSeqOutputFile.xlsx" 'To different workbook

'Close the saved copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code

Comment: Sorry. Automation Error occurs when executed for the second time.

Comment: After you've moved the sheet the first time and closed the resulting file how can you move it again?  It might help to explain exactly what workbooks are open when this is run, and exactly what happens between the two runs, if anything.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `DisplayAlerts` line - do you get different messages between first and second run?

Comment: comment out the Display Alerts- Same messages pop up. whether to replace existing File.  YES for first time works, YES for second time Excel gets closed.

Comment: Seqmergesheet will be created in the initial stage and the above mentioned is the last part. Though this works fine in Excel 2010. any number of times.

Comment: May not be related, but you should **always** specify the file **type** when using `SaveAs`.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will allow us to replicate (and then, hopefully, fix) the issue.

Comment: Issue is fixed. I have used a Form control button instead of ActiveX control Buttom

Comment: @Soumya I have the same problem, but using form control button did not work for me. Any other idea?